# Freeing the memory when pop from stack of struct

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct, stack

I use a stack of struct.

```
struct stack_values {
    long long int sp;
    bool sign; //true=sum, false=sub
    long long int imm;
};
static std::stack<stack_values> sosp;
```

I push to the stack with this code;

```
stack_values sosp_values;
sosp_values.sp = 0; 
sosp_values.sign = true;
sosp_values.imm = 0;
sosp.push(sosp_values);
```

And I wonder when I call `sosp.pop();` does `C++` free the memory which it allocated for the `sosp_values` when I pushed.

If it does not. How can I free the memory.

```
stack_values top = sosp.top();
sosp.pop();
delete top;
```

The above code did not work because the variable top is not a pointer.

Comment: What makes you think that `std::stack` doesn't free the memory when elements are `pop()`ed?

Comment: I have a huge stack with unexpected values. So I wonder if the problem is because of the memory allocation or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push the structure the stack copies it in its internal memory creating a new object that is a copy of the argument of the method push. When you call method pop then the stack calls the destructor of the corresponding internal object.

Here is a simple demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl; }
    A( const A & ) { std::cout << "A::A( const & )" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::stack<A> st;

    std::cout << "Calling push()" << std::endl;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) st.push( A() );

    std::cout << "\nCalling pop()" << std::endl;
    while ( !st.empty() ) st.pop();
}
```

The program output is

```
Calling push()
A::A()
A::A( const & )
A::~A()
A::A()
A::A( const & )
A::~A()
A::A()
A::A( const & )
A::~A()

Calling pop()
A::~A()
A::~A()
A::~A()
```

However destroying objects does not mean that the stack frees already allocated memory. It can reserve it for future elements that could be pushed on the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very clear explanation.